# Using the job RSS feed for a free feature on a platform with subscription model

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, rss, terms-of-service

I was wondering about the definition of the term ‘non-commercial’ in the context of Stack Overflow. Specifically in regards to this question: [Can I scrape Stack Overflow job postings?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348954/can-i-scrape-stack-overflow-job-postings)

If we are a free to use platform to anyone on the internet, do we fall under the definition of ‘non-commercial’?
We have a subscription model, but this feature will free to all users.